# If Lady Liberty's Skin Were Bronze

Tags: construction, materials

The last time I talked about an alternate Lady Liberty, I asked for the effect of her larger size--raising the height from 150 to 503 feet.  What I got was that ships from within 25 miles of New York Harbor would see her torch, which has become an actual torch, much like a lighthouse.

There is one other change to this alternate Lady Liberty, and it involves her skin.  Our Liberty's skin was a series of copper plates, each one 3/32nd of an inch thick--that's twice as thick as a penny.  The moment she was finished in 1886, the hostile, rainy climate of New York immediately set to work the chemical weathering that would turn Liberty's glowing bronze skin into a dull green.  The job was 100% done in 1920.

This alternate Lady Liberty has skin consisting of **bronze** plates **1/4 of an inch thick**.  Would this make her more resistant to oxidation?  Or would a bronze Lady Liberty turn green (or whatever color bronze oxidizes into) as quickly as the copper Lady Liberty?

Comment: You are just asking how bronze oxidizes, which is not a question about worldbuilding.

Comment: @Philipp  That is an oversimplification.

Comment: With modification, you might have better luck on Chemistry.SE

Comment: How is this not worldbuilding?  It is essentially the creation of fantasy, so why is this "off-topic"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, yes. Bronze is an alloy of copper and tin, which is why bronze exposed to air eventually turns black---copper oxidises to copper (II) oxide, CuO. From what I understand, this is what the Statue of Liberty was designed to do, to commemorate the emancipation of slaves in the continental US. Except that it was placed in a marine environment, so the oxidation remained incomplete at copper (I) oxide, Cu2O. 
A bronze statue would react the same way: the tin wouldn't visibly oxidise, the copper would turn green.